# Using grep and awk with shell expansion in a bash file, quotes escaping issue

Tags: bash, awk, grep

The following command works from the command line:

```
$  grep ".*" /some/long/path/*-version --exclude=X-version | awk -F ":" '/1/ {print $2}'
1.0.0
```

However when trying the same from a bash script I have issues. I'm pretty sure it's because I'm not escaping some of the quotes correctly. I tried several different combinations, this is my current attempt:

```
DIR="/some/long/path"
VERSION=$(grep ".*" "${DIR}/*-version" --exclude=X-version | awk -F ":" '/1/ {print $2}')
```

When executing this outputs

```
grep: /some/long/path/*-version: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try replacing `"${DIR}/*-version"` with `"${DIR}"/*-version`

Comment: Show us how your version files look like. You don't need to use grep + awk here, just `awk` alone should be good

Comment: @Inian I'm using grep because I need to exclude a file, I did not find a way to do that with `awk` alone

Comment: @DeepSpace: You can do that in `awk`. Provide a sample snippet of your `version` files and the filename you want to exclude

Comment: You don't need grep at all (`awk` has a FILENAME variable you could check), but if you did need `grep`, you could do `grep '.' ` instead of `grep '.*'`.  There's no need for the `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea seems right, but there are a couple of unwarranted instances where you are escaping the quotes

```
VERSION=$(grep ".*" "${DIR}"/*-version\" --exclude=X-version | awk -F \":\" '/1/ {print $2}')
#                                     ^^^                             ^^^^^^
```

You don't need to quote the glob string in `grep`, which should just be written as below. The quotes prevent your shell glob expansion from happening. Unlike the regex you define for `grep` which needs to be preserved literally, the glob expansion needs to/will happen even before the actual command is executed

```
grep ".*" "${DIR}"/*-version
```

The quotes around the `-F` are also not required. The `-F` argument of `awk` accepts a regular expression, so unless the de-limiter is a shell meta-character, the de-limiter need not be quoted. So `-F ":"` or just `-F:` is sufficient

```
awk -F ":" '/1/ {print $2}'
```

Also, you never need to use `grep`/`awk` together to solve a single problem. `Awk` is in itself a Swiss-Army<sup>TM</sup> knife which can do a lot more than what `grep` can do.

Judging from your requirements, I think all you need is

```
awk 'FILENAME == "X-version" { next } /[.].*1/' /some/long/path/*-version
```

The regex `[.].*1` matches a literal dot `.` character with a greedy match for any characters and containing a `1` subsequently.